# Does mapping a child class in EF 4.1 require an ID property?

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

I am starting to move some code over to EF4.1 and I am having a problem loading child classes.

I found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322005/problem-modelling-relationship-in-entity-framework-using-code-first) and it looks like there's a way to map the child class but I was wondering if the ID columns in the parent class are required.

I thought it was "no code" to simply include a reference to the child class and the rest was taken care of.

Here's the current object model:

```
public class classMember
{
    public int MemberID {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
}

public class classReservation
{
    public int ReservationID {get; set;}
    public classMember Member {get; set;}
}
```

But loading the classReservation just gives null Members.

Do I need to include a property for the MemberID in classReservation as well as in classMember? It seems redundant from a design point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in order to have navigation properties from one entity to another, they must be declared as virtual in your POCO. So you would want this:

```
public class classReservation
{
    public int ReservationID {get; set;}
    public virtual classMember Member {get; set;}
}
```

This is because at runtime, EF actually subclasses your POCO using reflection. To make the navigation property work, it needs to be able to override it. This is why it has to be `virtual`.

To answer your second question, no, you do not need to have a "foreign key property" from the child entity to the parent entity. It helps EF, but is not necessary.

We are in the process of removing foreign key properties from our entity models. To do it, you still need to tell EF how to map the relationship in the db. This can be done in your DbContext class' OnModelCreating method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<classReservation>
        .HasRequired(r => r.classMember)
        .WithMany()
        .Map(x => x.MapKey("MemberId"));
}
```

You could also use HasOptional, WithRequiredDependent, etc, depending on the cardinality and multiplicity of the relationship.

Comment: Thanks. This works in my POC test code but not in the code base I'm migrating. There must be some other problem keeping it from loading.

Comment: This is apparently a different issue. I have created [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466929/why-do-some-subobjects-load-and-others-dont) to figure out why my object hierarchy isn't fully loading. But, thanks for helping me figure out that I'm not even asking the right question.