# Entity Framework One-Zer-One different behavior

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Suppose you want to create a parent-child relationship in a table of users that will be the type of zero to one, we want to add further in the same way gender.

```
public class Gender
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int GenderID { get; set; }

    public virtual string GenderName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

and Userprofile

```
public class UserProfile
{

    [Key]
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual UserProfile UserParent { get; set; }

    public virtual int? ParentUserId { get; set; }

    public virtual String UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual Gender Gender { get; set; }

    public virtual int? GenderID { get; set; }

  }
```

for clarity

```
       modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>()
            .HasOptional(c => c.UserParent);

        // User -> Gender
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>()
            .HasOptional(g => g.Gender);
```

[image]

Everything looks good, but at the moment I can not retrieve the data obtained from the Parent UserName.

```
   public IQueryable<UserProfileListViewModel> UserAllVM
    {
        get
        {
            var uservm = context.UserProfiles
                .Select(l => new UserProfileListViewModel
                { 
                    UserId = l.UserId,
                    UserName = l.UserName,
                    ParentUserId = l.ParentUserId ?? 0,
                    //ParentUserName = this.context.UserProfiles.Where(e => e.UserId == l.ParentUserId).FirstOrDefault().UserName ?? "",
                    ParentUserName = l.UserParent.UserName, **// this way make always null**
                    GenderID = l.GenderID ?? 0,
                    GenderName = l.Gender.GenderName ?? "",
                });

            return uservm;
        }
    }
```

Commented out the way now obtains parent UserName. Question is why I can't retrive Parent UserName - I miss sth ?

Tx for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model configuration is incomplete, [see the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322005/problem-modelling-relationship-in-entity-framework-using-code-first).

You can either use the `[ForeignKey]` attribute ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute.aspx)) on either `UserProfile.UserParent` or `UserProfile.ParentUserId` (same thing with `UserProfile.Gender` / `UserProfile.GenderId`)

Or you can define the relationship via the Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>()
  .HasOptional(u => u.UserParent)
  .WithMany()
  .AsForeignKey(u => u.ParentUserId)

// User -> Gender
modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>()
  .HasOptional(u => u.Gender)
  .WithMany(g => g.UserProfiles)
  .AsForeignKey(u => u.GenderID);
```

Comment: He could also rename ParentUserId to UserParentId - this way he follows EF convention and it will automatically associate the properties